# Find an unique identifier for an enum case to conform to Identifiable

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, immutability, rx-swift, rxdatasources

I am testing [RxDataSources](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources) which requires the models to conform to the `Equatable` and `IdentifiableType`(similar to `Identifiable` protocols.

I am using a unidirectional data flow to drive the UI and my model is the following enum:

```swift
enum ViewModelType: Equatable, IdentifiableType {
        case loading
        case post(Post)
        
        var identity: String {
            switch self {
            case .loading: return "???" // <-- What to choose here?
            case let .post(post): return String(post.id)
            }
        }
        
        static func == (lhs: ViewModel.ViewModelType, rhs: ViewModel.ViewModelType) -> Bool {
            switch (lhs, rhs) {
            case (.loading, .loading): return true
            case let (.post(l), .post(r)): return l == r
            default: return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Concerning the `.loading` ViewModelType, I have to find a possible stable unique identifier if I want to use multiple ViewModelType of this type at once like `[.loading, .loading, .loading]` or the diffing breaks from `identical identifier`.

I prepared a sample project to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/florianldt/RxDataSourcesIdentifiableType

Any ideas of possible stable unique identifiers I can find for this use case.

Comment: I think you need to change your design. Your 3 loading cells are, by definition, *not* identifiable. You physically cannot distinguish one loading cell from another. They are all the same.

Comment: How do you know the number of Posts before calling the fetchPosts function?

Comment: @DanielT. I don't. 3 loading cell is an arbitrary number, could be 2 or 4 it doesn't matter much

Comment: Then how do you decide the number of cells to display? What will you do if the post count is different than the cell count?

Comment: I set the number of loading cell to 3 arbitrary simply because it look good on the screen, you know on some app like Facebook or instagram, when you load the content you have multiple post skeletons. So it is like when loading -> 3 loading cells, then loaded -> x post cells

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer to account for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several changes you will need to make, all stemming from the fact that you are completely replacing your view model without regard to its previous state. When building a state machine, remember that the update is based on the input *and the previous state*. Here are the minimal changes you should make:

There is no need to build your own AnimatableSectionModelType. Simply use the one that the library provides. Replace your `SingleSectionModel` struct with the below:

```
typealias SingleSectionModel<T> = AnimatableSectionModel<String, T> where T: IdentifiableType & Equatable
```

Turn your `ViewModelType` into a struct instead of an enum:

```
struct ViewModelType: Equatable, IdentifiableType {
    let identity: UUID
    let post: Post?
}
```

By doing this, you assure that every value has an identity. You can tell that it is "loading" by the fact that `post` is nil.

Instead of completely replacing your view model every time it changes state, use its previous state to help determine the new state. This means removing your `init(state:)` function and adding these two functions:

```
func loading() -> ViewModel {
    ViewModel(
        state: .loading,
        viewModels: [
            ViewModelType(identity: UUID(), post: nil),
            ViewModelType(identity: UUID(), post: nil),
            ViewModelType(identity: UUID(), post: nil)
        ]
    )
}

func loaded(posts: [Post]) -> ViewModel {
    ViewModel(
        state: .loaded,
        viewModels: zip(viewModels, posts).map { ViewModelType(identity: $0.0.identity, post: $0.1) }
        + (posts.count > viewModels.count ? posts[viewModels.count...].map { ViewModelType(identity: UUID(), post: $0) } : [])
    )
}
```

Notice how now, all three view model types have different identities and when the posts come in, they are *not* changed. That is the key.

When you fetch your posts, you will need to use the previous state of the view model to make the updates:

```
private func fetchPosts() {
    viewModel.accept(viewModel.value.loading())
    Post.list()
        .subscribe(onSuccess: { [viewModel] posts in
            viewModel.accept(viewModel.value.loaded(posts: posts))
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

The rest of the changes should be pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

While I believe you shouldn't base your Data Sources on the state of whatever it is you're loading (if these are unique posts, try that post's ID instead), you can always use `UUID` (or, specifically, `UUID().uuidString` for a unique identifier string.

Comment: Yes I know that this is possible. I did try it and can remove the crash, however, it is an unstable identifier as at every state change the id change as the how ViewModel is rebuilt